# How to parse Json String having backslash

Tags: java, spring

I'm using SpringFramework RestTemplate to invoke post call. When I receive the response which is in this format
`"{\"Status\":\"success\"}"`

restTemplate.exchange("some url", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ServerResponse.class)

ServerResponse.java class

```
   @Builder
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   public class ServerResponse implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    
     @JsonProperty("Status")   
     public String status;
    }
```

And I'm getting error like this

(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"Status":"success"}'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:

Basically that backslashes to be removed without using `string.replaceAll` etc

Appreciate any of your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72372686/522444)

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here, that exception wouldn't be thrown because of the slashes.  Try replacing the `ServerResponse.class` argument of the `exchange` method with `String.class` and inspect the String that's coming back.  Also, consider reducing your model to only `@Getter` and `@Setter`, that's all you need to handle the response, you don't need a builder or all args constructor, the default provided by the language is sufficient.

Comment: The error message doesn't show any backslashes. What makes you think the string contains them?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. ServerResponse got adjusted and returning back as 
{
  "Status": "success"
}

Now the resttemplate is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@Jacksonized` Jackson annotation to your class to make Jackson use your builder.